# Display error for invalid Email Address under field at WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code snippet displays an error below empty required fields at checkout:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'checkout_empty_field_errors', 10, 4 );
 
function checkout_empty_field_errors( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
   if ( strpos( $field, '</label>' ) !== false && $args['required'] ) {
      $error = '<span class="error" style="display:none">';
      $error .= sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), $args['label'] );
      $error .= '</span>';
      $field = substr_replace( $field, $error, strpos( $field, '</span>' ), 0);
   }
   return $field;
}
```

Is it possible to display a similar error for invalid Email Address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce already checks for the validity of the email in the file: `/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js`.

It will add the `woocommerce-validated` class if the email is correct. While the `woocommerce-invalid-email` class if the email is invalid.

You can use a jQuery script to check if the `#billing_email_field` has the `woocommerce-invalid-email` class and add the error below the email field, like so:

```
// adds an error under the email field if the email is invalid
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_error_for_billing_email_field' );
function add_error_for_billing_email_field() {
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function($){
      $('form.checkout').on('change', '#billing_email_field', function(){
         if ( $(this).hasClass("woocommerce-invalid-email") ) {
            if ( $('.invalid_email_error').length < 1 ) {
               $('<span class="invalid_email_error" style="display:block">The email is invalid.</span>').insertAfter('#billing_email');
            }
         } else {
            $('.invalid_email_error').remove();
         }
      });
   });
   </script>
   <?php
}
```

When the email **is invalid**:

[image]

---

When the email **is valid**:

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Vincenzo. It works, but there's an issue. It adds a new error every time the email address gets entered incorrectly [(Screenshot)](https://ibb.co/873W1JX).

Comment: You must use `remove()` to prevent the code from being added multiple times. Did you change the `invalid_email_error` class? Or do you use `hide()` instead of `remove()`? For me it works correctly like this.

Comment: I used the exact same code snippet as in you answer.

Comment: [Here's a screen recording](https://files.fm/f/8v4wxm9yx)

Comment: @JOKKER You are right. I added a check to verify that the element does not exist.